# Lista não está sendo passada como parâmetro do método

Tags: c#, asp.net, variáveis, construtor

Preciso implementar é o método `RoutesBetween` pra traçar a rota entre um ponto e outro (nesse caso, ponto **A** e **E**).

Método de teste:

```
public void TestRoutesBetweenTwoPoints()
{
    var links = new ILink<string>[]
    {
        new Link<string>("a","b"),
        new Link<string>("b","c"),
        new Link<string>("c","b"),
        new Link<string>("b","a"),
        new Link<string>("c","d"),
        new Link<string>("d","e"),
        new Link<string>("d","a"),
        new Link<string>("a","h"),
        new Link<string>("h","g"),
        new Link<string>("g","f"),
        new Link<string>("f","e"),
    };

    var graph = new Graph<string>(links);
    var paths = graph.RoutesBetween("a", "e");

    var list = paths.ToEnumerable().ToArray();
    Assert.AreEqual(list.Length, 2);

    Assert.IsTrue(list.Any(l => String.Join("-", 1) == "a-b-c-d-e"));
    Assert.IsTrue(list.Any(l => String.Join("-", 1) == "a-h-g-f-e"));
}
```

Como eu vou varrer a lista (`links`) se ela não está sendo passada como parâmetro do método?

A classe, construtor e método:

```
namespace Graph
{
    public interface IGraph<T>
    {
        IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> RoutesBetween(T source, T target);
    }

    public class Graph<T> : IGraph<T>
    {
        public Graph(IEnumerable<ILink<T>> links)
        {

        }
    }

    publi IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> RoutesBetween(T source, T target)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoãoMartins eu estava fazendo essa edição agora :P

Comment: Então foi por segundos ;)

Comment: @TamaraAmorim quando for fazer uma pergunta coloque o texto do seu código, evite usar um print do seu editor. Isso facilita muito para quem vai responder sua pergunta e a apresentar um [MCVE]

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Leandro, Ok... Obrigada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode salvar a referência de "links" utilizando o argumento passado para o construtor:

```
public class Graph<T> : IGraph<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<ILink<T>> links;
    public Graph(IEnumerable<ILink<T>> links)
    {
        this.links = links;
    }
}
```

E depois acessar a variável links no método RoutesBetween.

```
public IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> RoutesBetween(T source, T target)
{
   // links -> tem valor
}
```